# Python - assign unique identifier for repeated rows

Tags: python, pandas

Using the repeat function I repeat a row but want to be able to differentiate between them with a unique indentifier such as 'Instance.'

Currently the code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
table = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID':['a','b'], 'freq': [2, 3], '2007' : [1000, 1500], '2008': [0,2000], '2009': [2000,3000]})
```

Output

```
   ID  freq 2007    2008    2009
0   a   2   1000    0       2000
1   b   3   1500    2000    3000
```

I then look to replicate the row for when freq is greater than 2

```
rep = [val-1 if val>2 else 1 for val in table.freq]
table.loc[np.repeat(table.index.values, rep)]
```

Output

```
   ID  freq 2007    2008    2009
0   a   2   1000    0       2000
1   b   3   1500    2000    3000
1   b   3   1500    2000    3000
```

Desired output

```
   ID  Instance  freq   2007    2008    2009
0   a      1       2    1000    0       2000
1   b      1       3    1500    2000    3000
1   b      2       3    1500    2000    3000
```

Any suggestions on an efficient approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

When you're replicating a row or value, you basically just make a copy of it and lose any uniqueness of it. So you'll have to add it post the repeat process.

If it's just about labeling the ID's with an instance you can do something like:

```
table['instance'] = table.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=True)
```